# Ruby On Rails: +1 option/vote button error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning ROR and working on a voting style application, I've got my four tables up and running **Users**, **Questions**, **Options** and **Answers** and I can write to the **Answers** table via MySQL and the total votes are displaying so far which is great.

I'm having a problem with getting a +1 button working (eventually it'll be unique per user but for now I just want to see it working).

I'm fairly certain my files are all setup correctly but I'm confused with what to put in my Questions "Show" view for the button, it might be a routes problem as it does say `undefined method 'upvote_option_path'` - any help would be greatly appreciated! If I've forgotten any files below let me know :-)

**Question's Show View:**

```
<% @question.options.each_with_index do |option, index| %>
   <p><%= option.option_text %></p>
   <p><%= pluralize(option.answers.count, "vote") %><br><br></p>
   <p><%= button_to '+1', upvote_option_path(option), method: :post %></p>
<% end %>
```

**Option's Controller upvote:**

```
def upvote
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @option = Option.find(params[:option_id])
    Answer.create(user_id: current_user.id, question_id: @question, option_id: @option)
end
```

**Routes file:**

```
resources :questions do
    resources :options do
        post 'upvote'
    end
end
```

**rake routes:**

```
question_option_upvote  POST  /questions/:question_id/options/:option_id/upvote(.:format)  options#upvote
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method upvote_option_path

According to your routes, there is no `upvote_option_path`, it should be `question_option_upvote_path`. Also the path takes two arguments as ***keys***(`:question_id` & `:option_id`), so you need to pass those two to the path.
The below should work

```
<%= button_to '+1', question_option_upvote_path(@question, option), method: :post %></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the initial problem, however there is a "template is missing" error now. Is this because I need a redirect at the end of the upvote def?

Comment: @classequalsarthur Yes. You need to use `redirect_to` to redirect to desired path.

Comment: Awesome, no errors now! They add to the database but they're adding "NULL" into `question_id` and `option_id`. Is there anything you can spot? Thanks, you've been awesome :-)

Comment: @classequalsarthur You need to change `question_id: @question, option_id: @option` to `question_id: @question.id, option_id: @option.id` in `Answer.create`.

Comment: Ohhhhh of course I see that now. Legend, really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0):

In rake routes you have this: `question_option_upvote`, in your view you have this: `upvote_option_path`. Pretty sure your view should say `question_option_upvote_path(option)`.